# Backpressure between Lagom services using streaming ServiceCall not working

Tags: scala, akka-stream, lagom, backpressure

Lagom: 1.5.4

Consider having a ServiceCall ([example](https://github.com/an-tex/lagom-backpressure/blob/master/hello-world-stream-impl/src/main/scala/com/example/helloworldstream/impl/HelloWorldStreamServiceImpl.scala#L18)):

```scala
def stream: ServiceCall[NotUsed, Source[Int, NotUsed]] = ServiceCall { _ =>
  Future.successful(
    Source(1.to(1000)).wireTap(msg => log.info(s"sending $msg"))
  )
}
```

When another service ([example](https://github.com/an-tex/lagom-backpressure/blob/master/hello-world-stream-client/src/main/scala/com/example/helloworldstream/impl/HelloWorldStreamClientServiceImpl.scala#L23)) is consuming this ServiceCall by e.g.:

```scala
val ticker = Source.tick(1.second, 100.millis, true)
helloWorldStreamService.stream.invoke().flatMap(_.zip(ticker).map {
  case (msg, _) =>
    log.info(s"received $msg")
    msg
}.runWith(Sink.seq))
```

You would expect the artificially slow consumer would slow down the producer.
Looking at the logs this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
sending 1
sending 2
sending 3
[...]
sending 1000

[1 second pause]

received 1
[100ms pause]
received 2
[100ms pause]
received 3
[...]
```

Am I missing any hidden buffers?

Example code:
https://github.com/an-tex/lagom-backpressure

run `sbt runAll`

and then execute `curl 127.0.0.1:[port of hello-world-stream-client service]/api/test`

to see the effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are system buffers exceeding the test size. On Mac OS there seems to be a 128kb (512kb burst) buffer. Outside of the buffers the backpressure works like a charm. I've updated the [github repo](https://github.com/an-tex/lagom-backpressure) with a bigger test size in case someone wants to play around.

Credit goes to [TimMoore](https://discuss.lightbend.com/u/TimMoore) who answered this question on [Lightbend Discuess](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/backpressure-between-lagom-services-using-streaming-servicecall-not-working-lagom-1-5-4/5478/2)